# How to measure run time of C++ code with older C++ (g++ 4.6.3) and older Boost library (1.46.1)?

Tags: c++, gcc, time

What is the recommended way to measure run time (wall time) in c++ when using 'older' versions?  g++ is 4.6.3 (not old, but not c++0x11, no -std=c++0x switch), boost is also older 1.46.1.

I've tried clock() which measures CPU cycles.  I've tried boost::timer() which also measures CPU cycles.  Do I have to use a C function?

If it matters, this is Ubuntu Linux with a 3.5 kernel.  I'd like to find out the best practice assuming I can't add a c++0x switch or upgrade the compiler or boost libraries.

For reference, I'm using the code below to test different functions.  The result is about 0.2 seconds, rather than the multiple seconds that I wait at the cin call.

```
{
  boost::timer t;

  for (int i = 0; i < 99999999; i ++) ;

  std::string sin;
  std::cin >> sin;

  std::cout << t.elapsed() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use C/POSIX:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...);
```

It's convenient to wrap it into a C++ function so you don't have to deal with the `timespec` struct members; better to just join everything into a `long long` or `double`.

Example:

```
double getTimeInSeconds()
{
    struct timespec result;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &result))
        throw ...something...;
    return result.tv_sec + (result.tv_nsec / 1000000000.);
}
```

You might have to link against librt (i.e. add `-lrt` to the linker options) and maybe pthreads.

Answer (score 0):

The boost::timer was implemented by clock(). For linux, the return value of clock() included in time.h was the **cpu time** your program occupied, not the time you program **elapsed**, dividing by **CLOCKS_PER_SEC**. It refers to `man 3 clock`. According to your code, `std::cin >> sin;` doesn't occupy the CPU time.

The **boost timer class**:

```
class timer
{
 public:
  timer() { _start_time = std::clock(); } // postcondition: elapsed()==0
   ...
  double elapsed() const                  // return elapsed time in seconds
    { return  double(std::clock() - _start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; }

 private:
  std::clock_t _start_time;
};
```

Comment: The interfaces are the same across all platforms, but the semantics differ according to platform. Wall-clock time is measured on Windows, while CPU time is measured on POSIX-like systems. [reference of boost timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/timer/doc/index.html)